# Can't remove python package

Tags: python, package, uninstallation

I'm trying to remove a package I apparently installed sometime ago (can't remember really) and I'm finding it harder than I thought it would be (the package's name is `astropy`).

If I do:

```
import pip
inst_packgs = pip.get_installed_distributions()
inst_packgs_lst = ["%s" % (i.key) for i in inst_packgs]
print inst_packgs_lst
```

the package *is* listed as installed.

but if I try:

```
pip list
```

the package is *not* listed as installed.

If I do:

```
pip search astropy
```

the package is listed as an available package in PyPi.

If I try:

```
pip uninstall astropy
```

I get:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement astropy, not installed
Storing debug log for failure in /home/gabriel/.pip/pip.log
```

Why is this not working? How should I remove this package from my system?

---

**UPDATE**

`pyenv` is installed in my system and it was set to a different version locally, which is why the package didn't show. Sorry everybody, this question should be closed/deleted.

Comment: Does the log file say anything useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for completeness sake.

`pyenv` was installed in my system and it was set to a different version locally, which is why the package didn't show.

Answer (score 1):

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_search.html

```
pip search your_query
```

"searchs for PyPI packages whose name or summary contains your_query".

astropy exists in PyPI but is not installed in your system

Try :

```
pip list
```

instead to get a list of installed packages.

Comment: `pip list` does not show it as installed but `pip.get_installed_distributions()` _does_. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure I am making use of such package regularly.